# MSSQL select customers with same products

Tags: sql-server

Hello I would like to SELECT the name of the customer who ordered this set of products like the Brazilian customers from Northwind database. I did brazilian products here:

```
select [ProductName] 
from [dbo].[Products] join [dbo].[Order Details] on [dbo].[Products].ProductID = [dbo].[Order Details].ProductID
join [dbo].[Orders] on [dbo].[Order Details].OrderID = [dbo].[Orders].OrderID
join [dbo].[Customers] on [dbo].[Orders].CustomerID = [dbo].[Customers].CustomerID
where [Country] = 'Brazil'
```

but what now? How I can find them? I tried to do:

```
select [CompanyName], [ProductName]
from [dbo].[Customers] join [dbo].[Orders] on [dbo].[Orders].CustomerID = [dbo].[Customers].CustomerID 
join [dbo].[Order Details] on [dbo].[Order Details].OrderID = [dbo].[Orders].OrderID
join [dbo].[Products] on [dbo].[Products].ProductID = [dbo].[Order Details].ProductID
where  [ProductName] in  (
select [ProductName] 
from [dbo].[Products] join [dbo].[Order Details] on [dbo].[Products].ProductID = [dbo].[Order Details].ProductID
join [dbo].[Orders] on [dbo].[Order Details].OrderID = [dbo].[Orders].OrderID
join [dbo].[Customers] on [dbo].[Orders].CustomerID = [dbo].[Customers].CustomerID
where [Country] = 'Brazil')
```

but this also doesn't work :/

Comment: What doesnt work??

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 [**Tips better SQL Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand the schema wrong. Products from Brazil need check against suppliers

```
  SELECT ProductID
  FROM Products P
  JOIN Suppliers S
    ON P.SupplierID = S.SupplierID
  WHERE S.Country = 'Brazil'
```

Then customer buying Brazil products are

```
 SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerID
 FROM Customer C
 JOIN Orders O
   ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
 JOIN OrderDetails OD
   ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
 WHERE OD.ProductID IN ( SELECT ProductID
                         FROM Products P
                         JOIN Suppliers S
                           ON P.SupplierID = S.SupplierID
                         WHERE S.Country = 'Brazil')
```

Comment: I wasnt even sure if understand your question correctly. Glad that help, but be more precise in your question next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since CompanyName is on the Customer table in your original query, just select it from there.

```
select
    [CompanyName]
  , [ProductName]
from
    [dbo].[Products]
    join
        [dbo].[Order Details]
        on
            [dbo].[Products].ProductID = [dbo].[Order Details].ProductID
    join
        [dbo].[Orders]
        on
            [dbo].[Order Details].OrderID = [dbo].[Orders].OrderID
    join
        [dbo].[Customers]
        on
            [dbo].[Orders].CustomerID = [dbo].[Customers].CustomerID
where
    [Country] = 'Brazil'
```

Comment: but now i will have only Company and Product from Brazil, my task is to select customers from other country with same products

Comment: oh .. I assumed [Country] was for the product since you said `I did brazilian products` and you don't use aliases.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question (which is phrased not clearly), all you need to do is to add `[Customer]` to your `select` statement, instead of running nested queries. Your question asks to select the name of the customer, so it is `select [Customer]`, not `[Company], [Product]`.

Hope that helps.